# What's the best android phone to get as a developer

Tags: android

I know you can get a developer phone but the new G2 looks pretty nice as well as the Samsung around the corner.
I would assume however that it would be a better idea to be using a consumer phone if they are the target market for apps you wish to produce, especially for testing purposes.

Has anyone else had experience from this choice and provide any further illumination to the issue?

Comment: I dunno but that developer phone looks pretty awesome

Comment: I vote Dev Phone 1 with the cool design

Comment: Note that this question is absurdly dated! In May of 2009, this was a good answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

G1. It is the only phone with a hard keyboard. When the keyboard is opened up you will get several events/activity relaunches that will not happen on the touch screen only phones.  If you are doing apps it really doesn't matter if you get the dev version or retail one.

Going forward, you are probably going to  need to get several phones as the hardware diverges. For example the samsung has a 5way instead of a trackball. Depending on  how you are using the trackball, that could be a significant difference.

But as far as looks, get the samsung. It is by far the best looking android phone that I have seen so far.

Comment: I'll add that a friend of mine wanted to get the Samsung but was turned off the reviews, there are some hardware issues apparently....

Comment: Even with faster and bigger phones in the market, like the nexus one and the droid. A G1 is a good phone to have to test your apps because it shows the minimal screen, memory, cpu speed you app should use. 

Don't be fooled by how snappy you app is on the nexus one

Answer (score 8):

If you're just building consumer apps it doesn't matter. They all have debugging capabilities. The developer phone is mostly just beneficial if you're hacking on the OS since it isn't locked down by the carriers.

I've been using a G1 for months and had no problems. If you want the better camera and don't mind the lack of a keyboard then the  Magic/Sapphire/myTouch/G2/whatever-they're-calling-it-now will be fine, they're otherwise identical.

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the ADP2 device. Google gave some out at Google IO 2009 and wil give more out a dev conference or you can await to order it when it shows up on the Adp order pages.

Performance wise its a different hardware device than G1/Adp1.

It does matter you need an ADP device to do full debugging as you need full root access to do full  debugging. Do not be fooled by the answers before me , ADP device required! The Device Debug bridge that integrate with IDEs requires root device access.

Comment: What is your definition of "Full" debugging? I haven't encountered any app level stuff that I can't debug on the G1.  If you are doing system work, the ADP device is a no brainer.
Performance (both CPU and graphics acceleration) is going to start to vary a lot between vendors. I prefer to have a slow machine for testing but YMMV.

Comment: No I am not referring to OS kernel work.  I am referring to getting a heap dump or profile/trace to debug java application code in which case you need root access to device to get those items. Hence an ADP class device with root access. Hence the name Application Developer Phone(ADP).

Comment: I haven't had that problem but I don't know exactly what your doing. And for what it is worth  ADP stand for Android Dev Phone. See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: "The Device Debug bridge that integrate with IDEs requires root device access." This is an outright fabrication. I use ADB every day on my G1 and have had no issues. Also, the documentation on how to develop on devices (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) contradicts this.

Comment: I never claimed that ADB required root access. Its still desirable to have the ADP device to access all features required to optimize code.