# Android device for web development

Tags: android

I'm not sure if such question is suitable for Stack Overflow because it doesn't include code but since "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers" I bet that many programmers are wondering exactly this and some (like me) know nothing about Android devices but are forced to prepare a website for that platform.

So, the question would be: what Android device, in reasonable price range, is best for web development? It's a pity that their simulator is buggy and too slow on Windows machines. Up to date device seems to be a good time-saver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best android phone to get as a developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930424/whats-the-best-android-phone-to-get-as-a-developer)

Comment: @JoshLee I don't see an answer to this question in the thread that you linked to and they are actually not related. That person is asking about locked vs. unlocked phone differences - not about actual phone models.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Buying Android Device for Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504679/buying-android-device-for-development)

Comment: @AleksG You are linking to 'possible duplicate' from 2009 without even reading its content.

Comment: @JoshLee That question is really old. A G1 would  no longer be recommended

Answer (score 1):

I have one HTC Wildfire ( for bad small screens ) , had one HTC Desire (bravo) but I broke it :( , one HTC Desire HD for Good screen and single-core cpu and now I bought a used HTC One S which is a dual-core high res phone. I also have one 7 inch cheap Chinese tablet which is good only for testing.

In general , your apps should be working good in low-end devices, like htc wildfire, samsung galaxy mini/ace. If your performance is acceptable in these devices, then your app will be very good in top-end devices ( like HTC One .., Samsung galaxy s3 etc).

The problem comes when you want to see how the GUI looks like in different screens. So in my case I have one phone with very small screen , one with a good resolution and one with high resolution. Most modern devices are covered in these cases, the rest you can see how they will look when creating the layout xml in eclipse and viewing the result ( no need to open the emulator , except for dynamic data ). When viewing how the xml will look like, eclipse give you the ability to display it in many different screens ( or even custom sized ones ).

Comment: That's a good set of recommendations :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment to your question, but I don't have enough internet points for that.

I just want to address one part of your comment:  "It's a pity that their simulator is buggy and too slow on Windows machines."  I had the same sentiment (It'd take me around five seconds to step from one line of code to another), until I installed the x86 emulator.  Suddenly, the operation was blazingly fast.  This is largely because the x86 emulator is able to use the CPU's VM acceleration.

Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) if interested.

Comment: I have installed this accelerator they recommended and indeed it improved things 10 times but it is still 5 times too slow :(